# centos 5.5 how to set scheduled time for start and stop httpd and mysql

Tags: apache, centos

Server: `centos 5`

idia is to set auto job on server to keep service of httpd start from `1:00am` to `3:00 pm` and the rest time the service should be down.

is it possible to have script on server that could run this job automatically with out having it manaually:

```
sudo service httpd start
sudo service httpd stop
```

means the mention job should be on script

so far i have used:

```
crontab -e
```

have added bellow line on crontab

```
00 03 * * * bush /scripts/stop.sh
```

this is the code for script of **stop.sh** in /script/stop.sh

```
sudo service httpd stop
```

but still i am getting no result mean the httpd service is start status.

regards

Comment: Thought about creating a cron job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this a solution:

first we need to add the path to **crontab**
edit the crontab and add the following line:

```
crontab -e
```

add:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
01  01 * * *     service httpd start
01  15 * * *     service httpd stop
```

and same for any other service on centos.

Answer (score 2):

Setup a cron job. `man crontab` for more information. Type `crontab -e` when logged in.  For your situation where `httpd` starts at **1:00am** and stops at **3:00am** (crontab contents):

```
00 01 * * 1,2,3,4,5    /usr/sbin/sudo /sbin/service httpd start
00 03 * * 1,2,3,4,5    /usr/sbin/sudo /sbin/service httpd stop
```

When you're done adding the `crontab` lines, use `:wq` to write the contab and quit back to the shell.  You should then see:

`crontab: installing new crontab`

Comment: i did use this code but it's nto resulting same the httpd is started and it's not stoping